# Is [svgz] really worth a dedicated tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just browsing the newly created tags when I noticed the [svgz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svgz) tag.

Which is created and currently being added to "a lot" of questions by a [specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845869/james-a-mohler?tab=activity).

My spidey sense tells me this is not a very useful tag, because it is simply a gzipped svg file. But I want to double check with people considering I am not 100% sure this warrants a separate tag.

Especially considering that basically every question I have checked boils down to a single question and answer:

Q: Halp it does not work
A: Set the gzip encoding

So: should the tag just be killed or is there some actual value in it I am missing?

Comment: Wait.  So it's *just* a compressed SVG file?  That's a synonym of SVG then.

Comment: That user also fails to do any other cleanup while introducing his new tag...

Comment: Or better yet a synonym of gzip, since it appears that the compression is more pertinent than the file format.

Comment: If it just boils down to a single question, shouldn't they be closed as duplicates?

Comment: They probably should. But that is out of the scope of this question. As in I left it out on purpose.

Comment: More info on svgz for those who need it http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24797/when-should-i-use-svg-or-svgz-for-my-web-graphics
Not worth a tag imo

Comment: Yeah I don't think the tag is worth it unless for some reason gzipped svg files behave differently than other gzipped files

Comment: Probably not worth a separate tag. OTOH, working with SVGZ data can be painful. Eg, browsers that happily accept SVGZ files and inlined SVG (both in <svg> tags and as data: URIs) may reject SVGZ data URIs in an HTML document.

Comment: @PM2Ring Simply because it's painful to work with, it doesn't mean that the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: It isn't even worth a separate name as a format, never mind a tag.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Maybe you misunderstood me. Yes, my initial remark is that it's probably not worth a separate tag. But "OTOH" means On The Other Hand, so I'm saying that the quirks associated with SVGZ _may_ warrant a separate tag for it. However, I don't see why such quirks cannot be adequately covered under the main SVG tag. And even if we do decide to keep the SVGZ tag any questions with that tag ought to be tagged with the main SVG tag too: I can't imagine SVG experts wanting to specialize in SVGZ-only questions.